# secure channel (SC) reset on DC failed with error: no logon servers available

Tags: active-directory

I'm struggling to resolve this error. 
I think I've correctly set up the DNS-part, by creating Secondary Zones for forward and reverse look-up. I can ping all servers, ports are open etc. At some point, I can validate the trust perfectly. But when I check again at a later point (now = next day), I'm getting this error (I had this before, first tried recreating everything).

> **The outgoing trust was successfully validated.**
>
> The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller
>   \DC-02.mydomain2.local of domain mydomain2.local  to domain
>   intranet.mydomain1.local failed with error: There are currently no
>   logon servers available to service the logon request.

Domain controllers:

- **mydomain2**: DC-01, DC-02
- **mydomain1**: has 4 domain controllers, DNS is NOT on the primary domain controller (still need to promote the new DNS server to PDC as well).

The issue always mentions DC-02, not sure if this is relevant?
What should I check?

I also tried resetting the password, as suggested. That leads to a "No Logon servers are available" error.

---

**Update**: when validating again from domain 1, it claims the RPC server is unavailable. Further investigation: it seems all of a sudden, from the PDC, I can't ping by the name of the domain or domain controllers of domain2. I double-checked this yesterday, then it worked. From other domain controllers in domain 1, it still works. I disabled Kaspersky Endpoint Security, then ran a **ipconfig /flushdns** and tried again: working. Could it be Kaspersky, or a DNS-issue (weird, since the same DNS-servers are used and on other DC's it's working?)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the following:

1. In the Condintional forwarders in DNS setting - Add the other domain's DNS server name and IP.
2. Open ncpa.cpl - Goto properties of IPv4 and then click on advanced.
   Goto DNS - clcick on the radio button - "Append these DNS suffixes (in order):"
   Then add the domain - e.g. lab.com in it.

Perform the above two steps in both the domain's Domain controllers/DNS servers.